# Unsure How To Add A Linked List Before Target Number

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm not sure how to add a Linked List before a target number. My class was written like this:

```
public class IntNode {

    public int data;
    public IntNode next;

    public IntNode(int data, IntNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static IntNode addBefore(IntNode front, int target, int newItem) {

        while(front.next != null) {
            if(front.data == target) {
                IntNode neww = new IntNode(newItem,null);
                neww = front;
                front = neww.next;
                return neww;
            }
            front = front.next;
        }
        return front;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IntNode a = new IntNode(7,null);
        IntNode b = new IntNode(9,null);
        IntNode c = new IntNode(2,null);
        IntNode d = new IntNode(4,null);
        IntNode e = new IntNode(0,null);
        IntNode f = new IntNode(8,null);

        a.next = b;
        b.next = c;
        c.next = d;
        d.next = e;
        e.next = f;

        addBefore(a,4,15);

        IntNode ptr = a;

        while(ptr != null) {
            StdOut.println(ptr.data);
            ptr = ptr.next;
        }


    }
    
}
```

From this class, I tried to write neww = front; and front = neww.next; but instead when Java was printing out the data, it missed out the number I wanted to insert. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You want to check if the *next* `IntNode` equals the `target`, so that you can insert the new element before that. The insertion is fairly simple: You create a new `IntNode` (`neww`) that has its `next` IntNode set to the target (`front.next`) and you then override the `next` IntNode field before the target to be the `neww` IntNode.

```
public static IntNode addBefore(IntNode front, int target, int newItem) {

    while(front.next != null) {
        if(front.next.data == target) {
            IntNode neww = new IntNode(newItem,front.next);
            front.next = neww;
            return neww;
        }
        front = front.next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you create the new node but then override it with front a line later. The correct order of commands is first create, put front.next into neww.next and lastly put neww into front.next.